# Can't get material from a gltf loaded scene in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'd like to modify the material in a gltf loaded model to set its opacity/transparency.

I can't seem to get any meshes.  I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9tw02hd) that says 'no mesh found'.  I have found quite a few examples of getting material and they all seem to do it this way (making sure it's mesh then getting the material).

```
<style>
  canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
  }

</style>

<canvas id="canvasid"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>-->

<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
          "imports": {
            "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/build/three.module.js"
          }
        }
    </script>

<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x6699cc);
const lights = [];
lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
lights[0].position.set(0, 100, 0);
lights[1].position.set(100, 100, 100);
lights[2].position.set(- 100, - 100, - 100);
scene.add(lights[0]);
scene.add(lights[1]);
scene.add(lights[2]);

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/DamagedHelmet.gltf", function (gltf) {
    const mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
    scene.add(mesh);

    //my main question is about this code - looks like everyone can test if isMesh, then can get the material.  I have tried multiple models and can never find any mesh.  If I just assumme a material that doesn't work either
    gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
        if (o.isMesh) {
            console.log("found mesh");
            console.log(o && o.material);
        } else {
            console.log("no mesh found");
        }
    });
}, undefined, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasid");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(canvas.parentElement.clientWidth, canvas.parentElement.clientHeight);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(1, canvas.parentElement.clientWidth / canvas.parentElement.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 100;

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.update();
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.enableDamping = true;
var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    renderer.setSize(canvas.parentElement.clientWidth, canvas.parentElement.clientHeight);

    camera.aspect = canvas.parentElement.clientWidth / canvas.parentElement.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}, false);

animate();
```

How can I access the mesh/material?

Answer (score 1):

The traverse does not work since you add the first child of `gltf.scene` to `scene`. That means you change the object hierarchy and thus break the traversal.

To fix this, simply move the below two lines of code after the call of `Object3D.traverse()`.

```js
const mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
scene.add(mesh);
```

Also, consider to just do this since a glTF asset does not necessarily only have a single child mesh:

```js
scene.add(gltf.scene);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftcnby9e/